# How to stub "respondsToSelector" method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ocmock

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
id synchronizerDelegate = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(SynchronizerDelegate)];
BOOL isRespondsToSelector = NO;
[[[synchronizerDelegate stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(isRespondsToSelector)] respondsToSelector:@selector(didLoadFullImage:)];
GHAssertFalse([synchronizerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didLoadFullImage:)], nil);
```

Here is the definition of SynchronizerDelegate

```
@protocol SynchronizerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didLoadFullImage:(NSData *)data;
@end
```

But this test case always fail (the returned value is YES).

Anyone tried to stub "respondsToSelector" method before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mockForProtocol, the mock doesn't actually conform to the protocol, so [`OCProtocolMockObject` overrides `respondsToSelector`](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/tree/master/Source/OCMock) to return YES for methods defined in the protocol.

OCMock depends on `forwardInvocation:`, which is invoked by the runtime when an object hasn't defined the method being called. Since `OCProtocolMockObject` implements `respondsToSelector`, you can't mock it.

If you describe what you're trying to achieve, there might be another way to approach it.

Comment: More detailed discussion of this topic on the OCMock forum: http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=247

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I actually I found a way to test both code paths (responds to selector and does not respond) when you do this to check for a system-feature (like the new localization permissions in iOS 8).

This is my spec:

```
it(@"asks for location permission on viewDidLoad", ^{

    id locationManagerMock = OCMClassMock([CLLocationManager class]);

    if([locationManagerMock respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [[locationManagerMock expect] requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    else {
        [[locationManagerMock expect] startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    [sut setLocationManager:locationManagerMock];
    [sut view];

    [locationManagerMock verify];

});
```